# How to get the url of called method resteasy

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, resteasy

I making one Rest Service with Restaeasy (java) that have to return the same URL that was called but with one new string

Example Call service:

Post => mybase/myservice/somewrite with some JSON
| Reponse =>  mybase/myservice/somewrite/123456

So i want to make the **mybase/myservice/somewrite** url with one generic logic, because if i put `String returnURL="mybase/myservice/somewrite";` and i change for example the name of `mybase` the reponse will not be good

I want somthing like this

```
someLogicService(JSON);
id=getId();
URL=getContextCallURL();
return URL+\/+id;
```

But i dont know if this is possible to do it, and less how to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also inject an instance of type `UriInfo` using the annotation `Context` within your resource, as described below:

```
@Context
private UriInfo uriInfo;

@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response makeContact(Contact contact)  {
    String requestUri = uriInfo.getRequestUri();
    (...)
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem, i put inject with @context the httpRequest to my function and call absolutPath :

```
 @POST
 @Path("/")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response makeContact(Contact contact, @Context HttpRequest request)  {
        return Response.ok().header("location", request.getUri().getAbsolutePath().getPath() + contactService.makeContact(contactJSON)).build();
    }
```